# How to replace specific characters in a String with different ones?

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

Given a

```
String text = "RHKKA";
```

How to efficiently replace all **'R'** with **'H'**, all **'H'** with **'E'**, all **'K'** with **'L'** and all **'A'** with **'O'**?

String text would be `HELLO` then.

Comment: Do you have mappings for an entire alphabet, or just those letters?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a Map of Character as key and value, then loop over character by character like so :

```
String text = "RHKKA";
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('R', 'H');
map.put('H', 'E');
map.put('K', 'L');
map.put('A', 'O');
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    chars[i] = map.get(chars[i]);
}
String result = String.valueOf(chars);
System.out.println(result.toString());//HELLO
```

---

### Java8+ possible solution

Or if you are using Java8+ you can use :

```
String result = text.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(map.get((char) c)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());//HELLO
```

---

### Java9+ possible solution

Another possible solution if to use [Matcher::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) like so :

```
String text = "RHKKA";
Map<Character, Character> map = Map.of('R', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'K', 'L', 'A', 'O');
text = Pattern.compile(".").matcher(text)
        .replaceAll(c -> String.valueOf(map.get(c.group().charAt(0))));//HELLO
```

---

You can read more about [Map.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-)

Comment: Of course, you need to ensure the mapping is complete (enough), otherwise your output string would be peppered with `null`s.

Comment: Also perhaps worth pointing out that you don't need the `StringBuilder` in the first way, you can just update the `char[]` from `toCharArray()`, and then build a new string from that. (Or construct the StringBuilder with the entire text, and update it one char at a time. Kinda the same approach.)

Comment: @AndyTurner did you mean something like [this demo](https://ideone.com/wvjsiI), also I don't get the last part *(Or construct the StringBuilder with the entire text, and update it one char at a time. Kinda the same approach.)*

Comment: @YCF_L yes. And for the second part, I meant that you could do largely the same with `StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text)` and charAt/set, since a `StringBuilder` is just a wrapper around a `char[]`.

Comment: Thank you @AndyTurner good idea I edit my answer with this one

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, for the Java9 Map.of() ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in standard Java but you can look at Apache Commons [StringUtils.replaceChars](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceChars%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which replaces group with another group in one go, effectively doing the same as Unix tr command:

```
StringUtils.replaceChars("RHKKA", "RHKA", "HELE") = "HELLO".
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to create a new `String` or `StringBuilder` by replacing all characters in the original one with the correct ones.
Something like:

```
String text = "RHKKA";
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(text.length());

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
     char newChar = text.charAt(i);
     if (text.charAt(i) == 'R')
         newChar = 'H';
     else if (text.charAt(i) == 'H')
         newChar = 'E';
     else if (text.charAt(i) == 'K')
         newChar = 'L';
     else if (text.charAt(i) == 'A')
         newChar = 'O';
     newString.append(newChar);
}
System.out.println(newString); //prints HELLO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way based on the character replacement:

```
String text = "RHKKA";

String before = "RHKA";       // before mapping
String after  = "HELO";       // after mapping

String output = Arrays.stream(text.split(""))                   // Split by characters
    .map(i -> String.valueOf(after.charAt(before.indexOf(i))))  // Replace each letter
    .collect(Collectors.joining(""));                           // Collect to String

System.out.println(output);   // HELLO
```

By the way, I am sure you meant to replace `A` with `O`.. not `E` as you have in the description.